# How to change collection name with dynamic name in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js project. In my project i want to use the collection( means model) name with dynamic name. In my code i will explain you about what my need actually is. This code is working fine.

```
    User.findById(req.param('id'),function(err,user){
    console.log('entered');
    if(err){
        res.json(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,{error:'unexpected error'});
        return;
    }
    if(user == null){
        res.json(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,{error:'user not found'});
        return;
    }
    console.log("success");
```

Here, my collection(model) name is User. But i want to use the value of the client as "collection name" by using the code below

```
   var temp = req.body.collectionName;  // example: var temp ='User';
```

Can i use value of the temp variable in the place of "User".findById. If not, can i get any possible solutions for this functionality to happen? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using Mongoose, in which case you can use `mongoose.model(MODEL_NAME)` to get a reference to a particular model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
...
var User = mongoose.model('User'); // or `req.body.collectionName`
User.find(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what framework and ORM you are using, so here's a simple way that you can use provided your model names are predetermined:

```
var collections = {
    "User": User,// reference for model User
    "Resource": Resource
};

var temp = req.body.collectionName; 
if (collections[temp]) {
    collections[temp].findById(req.param('id,), handler);
}
```

You should first try to find out if your ORM provides a list/mapping of models and use that if possible. Usually there is a hook or other inherent way of accessing them.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't work for me. I'm using express framework with node.js. I'm using mongoose as my middleware.

```
    var collections = {
    "User": User,// reference for model User
    "Resource": Resource
    };

    var temp = req.body.collectionName; 
    if (collections[temp]) {
    collections[temp].findById(req.param('id,), handler);
    }
```